# Stubbing a function in Golang

Tags: unit-testing, go

There's a function that keeps coming up in the code that I'm responsible for unit-testing (that hasn't even been tested yet), defined as follows:

```
//Get Retreives an error with the given access code.
func Get(code AccessCode) *ErrorSt {
    if err, ok := Errors[code]; ok {
        err.Stack = utilityCore.GetCleanStack(logger.Instance.GetProjectNames())
        return &err
    }
    err := NewError(string(ACPanic), fmt.Sprintf("Error '%s' can't be retreived.", code), ESSystem, SError)
    return err
}
```

It is invoked by a couple of the methods that I have tried to test thus far. My instinct is to either stub or [spy on](https://godoc.org/github.com/nyarly/spies) the function, but this fails.

This function is used in many places throughout my employer's APIs, thus I cannot change it (if I do, it will break a lot of things). Is there any way to do true unit testing and test-double it out?

My spy attempt:

```
type ErrorSpy struct {
    spies.Spy
}

func (spy *ErrorSpy) Get(code AccessCode) *ErrorSt {
    res := spy.Called(code)

    return res.Get(0).(*ErrorSt)
}
```

Comment: You are having trouble unit testing this specific function or you are having trouble because you want to unit test code that uses this function? Either way seems pretty straight forward

Comment: I want to unit-test code that *uses* this function.

Comment: This could be done using an interface. Try writing the code you want to test (which depends on `Get(AccessCode) *ErrorSt`) to depend on an interface type which provides this method. Then in your test code, you can provide a mock/stub implementation.

Comment: Like I said, if I do that, I'll break code in a lot of places, outside my job title and control.

Comment: I'll have to talk with the boss about this.

Comment: And what's the problem with testing code that uses this function? Its output is predictable.

Comment: I try to give it specifications on what state it should return and it not only fails those expectations, but assertions that the spy method was even called fails.

Comment: I don't see the logic in stubbing this out in the first place.

Comment: My bad, I'll add it, right after lunch.

Comment: I was right: the function is being used in too many places; /* If we refactor it into a method, it would break much of the existing code base */

I had to, since this function was trying to `Get` from the `Errors`, write to `Errors`. ick! (This isn't unit testing! WTF is this!?)

Answer (score 2):

Learned that spying is only doable on methods implemented from interfaces (I'm so used to Java, where **everything** is method!) I talked to the boss, and he said no to the proposal of refactoring this function, and all the instances in which it's used, to a method.

Failing that, I had to break the core principle of unit-testing and worry about what `Get` was returning. Luckily, in my case, it was trying to return an `ErrorSt` from the map `Errors`. Seeing that, I had to simply do the following:

```
errors := Errors
Errors = map[AccessCode]ErrorSt { 
    // anything I expect Get to return 
}

defer func() { Errors = errors }()
```

and then I was good to go.